# openACC: Running out of device memory when copying 3D array to device

Tags: c, openacc

I'm new to using openACC and am trying to figure out specifically what's going on when I used the `copyin` data directive (specifically in C).

I have a 3D array and am trying to copy it to the device to do some computation. The problem I have is that when I do the copy, the device runs out of memory, even though by my estimates the array should only be ~40 MB (20000 x 128 x 2 array of floats). I'm using a GTX 950 and when running there is over 1 GB of free memory available (checked using `nvidia-smi`).

Here's the code I'm using to test. I compiled it with
`pgcc -acc -Minfo -o copytest copytest.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


float ***create_test_array( int nsamples, int nchan, int npol )
{
    int s, ch; // Loop variables
    float ***array;

    array = (float ***)malloc( nsamples * sizeof(float **) );

    for (s = 0; s < nsamples; s++)
    {
        array[s] = (float **)malloc( nchan * sizeof(float *) );

        for (ch = 0; ch < nchan; ch++)
            array[s][ch] = (float *)malloc( npol * sizeof(float) );
    }

    return array;
}



void test_copy( int nsamples, int nchan, int npol, float ***arr)
{
#pragma acc data pcopyin(arr[0:nsamples][0:nchan][0:npol])
#pragma acc kernels
    for (int pol = 0; pol < npol; pol++)
    {
        for (int ch = 0; ch < nchan; ch++)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < nsamples; s++)
            {
                arr[s][ch][pol] = 0.0;
            }
        }

    }
}


void main()
{
    int nsamples = 10000;
    int nchan = 128;
    int npol = 2;
    float ***test_array = create_test_array( 2*nsamples, nchan, npol );

    test_copy( 2*nsamples, nchan, npol, test_array );
}
```

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very poor data layout for the GPU.  The problem being that the compiler must match the structure on the GPU and hence needs to create an array of pointers, then for each, create a second array or pointers and "attach" the pointer to it's parent.  "attach" means that it will fill in the device pointer in it's proper spot in the parent array but must launch a kernel to do it.  Worse, it then needs to traverse the structure again to create the third dimension and again attach the pointers.  The third dimension is also padded for alignment which is where the extra memory is coming from.  The causes a lot of extra overhead and will severely impact your performance.

Also since data transfers between the host and device can only be done on contiguous blocks, the runtime must traverse the structure and copy only 2 elements at a time.  Again, causing a high overhead.

If you can swap the "nsamples" and "npol" dimensions, you'll still have some overhead but 128+2x128 attaches is a lot less than 20000+20000x128.

Alternatively, you can use CUDA Unified Memory (-ta=tesla:managed) to have the CUDA runtime do the data movement for you.  The compiler no longer needs to create the GPU data structure nor attach the pointers.

A third option would be to linearize the array (i.e. make it a 1D array) and then compute the index in the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks Mat. I changed the code around so that instead of calling `create_test_array`, I just create it as `arr[nsamples][nchan][npol]` and that solved my problem (at least in terms of the memory issues). I suppose it's because now the array is all in one place in memory and so doesn't need to do the ridiculous amount of point creation and copying.

Comment: I had this very same issue and converting it into an array fixed it. However, I don't see the math behind this. Why would 20000+20000x128 be too much when it is only about 2.5M positions, if every position takes 8 bytes this would add up to a total of 40MB which is less than 0.1% of memory on a GTX 950. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not the size of the memory that's the problem, it's the larger number "attaches" (setting the device pointers) and small data transfers given that transfers can only be made in contiguous blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I was getting out of memory errors before converting it into an array, so this definitely fixed it. Regardless of potential performance issues, why would this change make it fit on the device memory? "but 128+2x128 attaches is a lot less than 20000+20000x128" But even if that many pointers are required, there's no way to fill 2GiB of device memory. That is the part I don't understand. Again, thank you very much for your help.